# Running example with react-router in typescript 1.6 with TSX

Tags: react-router, reactjs, typescript1.6

Has someone a complete running example of a react application using react-router but developped with typescript 1.6+ TSX ?

Comment: Please improve your question, give us the detailed problem. If possible, share the code, explain where is the problem and how to reproduce. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had one I named [generator-react-bootstrap-typescript-webpack](https://github.com/lgirma/generator-react-bootstrap-typescript-webpack):

You can find the applications router configured in `app.tsx` file. You can also find plenty in yeoman.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to add router to application

Install react-router-dom and types

1- **npm install react-router-dom --save npm install @types/react-router-dom --save-dev**

2- In your Index.tsx wrap the App component by

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>,
   document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
```

);

3- In the App component

```
export  const App : React.StatelessComponent = () => 
{
return  <div>
        <Route  exact={true}  path="/"   component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
        </div>
}
```

4-  Home and login component

```
export const HomePage = () => {
return <div>
       <h1> Home Page</h1>
       <Link  to="/login" >Login</Link>
       </div>
}

export const LoginPage : React.StatelessComponent = () => {
return <div>
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        </div>
}
```